# Initialization of the main activity, during the splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I need to that when i open the application, the screen saver works and the main activity opens. But so that during the splashscreen, the main activity is already loaded. In articles and videos, they do it via postdelayed, which does not suit me(that is, the user first waits for the splashscr, and then still waits for the main activity to load). I might as well use thrsleep. I was thinking of doing it through Asynctask and putting the opening in the background or onpreExecute, but then the activity will probably open immediately without a splashscr. Please help, or suggest an idea. I also came across this [article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) and [this](http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts), but the app also continues to load after the splash screen. The launcher activity in the manifest I have a login window. From it, it goes to the splashscr, and from there to the main activity.

Comment: Please add more details, first your objective, then your progress and then issue that you are facing...

Comment: Ok, in the main activity I have a subload of information about the user(that is, all his data), pageradapter with 6 fragments. The first one loads the chat with users and their latest messages. In the second fragment, schedule for this user(application for students). In the third, the news. Etc. The schedule contains the logic for highlighting the current lesson(If the lesson is over, it displays the next lesson.) And to download all this, it takes some time. I hope I described it in enough detail.